# Visual Studios: How to enable exception showing when mousing over methods and constructors?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have the following C# line in Visual Studio Community 2015:

```
StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader("Values.txt");
```

Currently, when I move my mouse over `new StreamReader("Values.txt")` I see:

> StreamReader.StreamReader(string path) (+ 10 overloads) Initializes a
>   new instance of the StreamReader class for the specified file name.

The problem is that it does not show me the five exceptions that this constructor can actually throw: ArgumentException, ArgumentNullException, FileNotFoundException, etc...

How can I enable it to show me these exceptions on mouse over event? I know that it is possible, because this functionality is used [in this training video](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/en-US/training-courses/c-fundamentals-for-absolute-beginners-8295) (about 10:05 on video titled "Gracefully Handling Exceptions").

Thank you.

Comment: I dont understand the reason for downvote?

Comment: Are you using Express edition?

Answer (score 1):

JetBrains ReSharper has support for an Plug-in which shows you what exceptions could happen

Answer (score 1):

I instantly knew what you was referring too:

[image]

I would really go along lines that it's version specific. I'm currently running 2013 Ultimate. I spent some time in VS to find on option to turn off/on, to no avail.

It certainly makes no sense to be version specific but I could not find an option.

Please note that I do not have the ReSharper plugin.